# GWT testing with mockito

Tags: gwt, testing, mvp, mockito

Simple Question:

Verification (1) passes.
Verification (2) does not. Why? How to fix it?

**Test**

```
  @Test
    public void test() {
            System.out.println("test");
            EventBus eb = mock(EventBus.class);
            MyWidget.View v = mock(MyWidget.View.class);
            GreetingServiceAsync s = mock(GreetingServiceAsync.class);

            HasClickHandlers button = mock(HasClickHandlers.class);

            when(v.getButton()).thenReturn(button);

            new MyWidget(eb, v, s);

            button.fireEvent(mock(ClickEvent.class));   

            verify(button).addClickHandler(any(ClickHandler.class)); (1)
            verify(v).alert(anyString()); (2)


        }
```

**Widget**

```
@Inject
    public MyWidget(EventBus eventBus, View view, GreetingServiceAsync service){
        this.view = view;
        this.service = service;

        bindView();
        bindEventBus();

    }

    private void bindView(){

        view.getButton().addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                view.alert("test");
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As David Wallace said, you are mocking the button. It does lose all its abilities.
you could fix this by making a ArgumentCatptor

```
ArgumentCaptor<ClickHandler> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(ClickHandler.class);
```

Then manually fire the function of the event by using:

```
captor.getValue().onClick(null);
```

This will fake the call that should have been made by the button.

If your class only has one button or one catcher for a specific event you can make it extend the ClickHandler class. Then you can just call the onClick of your class.

Answer (score 3):

because `button` is a mock, so calling `fireEvent` on it doesn't actually fire the event; and `onClick` is never called on the view.

Answer (score 1):

Because Button was mocked out and there is no implementation telling it what to do when fireEvent is called. See the line:

```
HasClickHandlers button = mock(HasClickHandlers.class);
...
button.fireEvent(mock(ClickEvent.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

That is what I did:

```
public class ClickableElement implements HasClickHandlers{

        ClickHandler ch;
        @Override
        public void fireEvent(GwtEvent<?> event) {
            ch.onClick((ClickEvent) event);
        }

        @Override
        public HandlerRegistration addClickHandler(ClickHandler handler) {
            this.ch = handler;
            return null;        
        }

    };
```